# Meanings of "carriage" in Enola Holmes

Tags: meaning, cinema, nineteenth-century-english

The following conversation takes place near the beginning of the movie [Enola Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enola_Holmes_(film))

> Mycroft: We didn't send for you silly girl, we sent for the carriage.
> Did you at least bring it?
>
> Enola: The carriage
>
> Mycroft: Yes
>
> Enola: *What carriage would you be wanting? Because I have a few in
> mind--*
>
> Mycroft: The carriage I pay for.

Mycroft obviously wants a horse-driven carriage to drive him home.
What are the "few" carriages that Enola "has in mind"?

The only thing that comes to mind is "the way you carry yourself". But that does not seem pertinent in the situation.

Answer (score 2):

A hearse.

She's telling him to drop dead.

Comment: I thought it might be a [gun-carriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_carriage) to shoot him with, but this seems more likely.

Comment: Why a hearse? Some context/explanation would be good.